# How to use copy_to on a nested field

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to use copy_to in a nested field :

Here is an extract of my mapping :

```
day: {
    type: nested
    properties: {
        weight: {
            index_name: bzixtz2fng.day.weight
            type: double
        }
        value: {
            index_name: bzixtz2fng.day.value
            type: string
            copy_to: [
                raw_words
                back
            ]
        }
    } 
}
```

Why I don't find my doc when I search on back

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "back": "one"
    }
  }
}
```

PS : Version 1.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an issue [#6701](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/6701) on elasticsearch, fix in v1.4.0.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the nested query or filter to wrap your term query as explained here: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html.

Something like this should work:

```
{
    "nested": {
        "path": "obj1",
        "score_mode": "avg",
        "query": {
            "nested": {
                "term": {
                    "obj1.back": "one"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If that doesn't help, please provide the mapping returned from /_mapping.

Comment: That doesn't help : I have a few fields with value and weight, and I want to copy to a global field to be able to search amongst all values.

Comment: OK, I did not get that from your original question. In any case, I don't think that what you want here is possible because copy_to is intended to be used on the same document and not on another document. The whole point of nested is to treat the nested document like a separate document. However, for aggregations there is a recently added way to refer back to the containing object and it would not be a strange thing to do the same here with copy_to. You might want to ask the same question in the mailing list. Many ES committers read that and might be able to be more helpful.